# What is first called - interceptor or authenticator? OkHttp, Retrofit

Tags: android, okhttp

As I read from docs, OkHttp uses lists to track interceptors, and interceptors are called in order.

But what is first being called a list of interceptors or an authenticator?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading the [source](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3), the authenticator is called by [`RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/0cc3aefa8ee328409bc6797e501308ba0b3c5e17/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/http/RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.kt#L223) that is [added to the call's interceptor list](https://github.com/square/okhttp/blob/0cc3aefa8ee328409bc6797e501308ba0b3c5e17/okhttp/src/main/kotlin/okhttp3/internal/connection/RealCall.kt#L175) after the client's interceptors. So, client interceptors are invoked first.

Comment: So, basically authenticator is an interceptor that is added after custom user interceptors?